# Additional condition to the Bollobas theorem (Sperner's therorem) in extremal set theory

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

The Bollobas'1965 theorem is the following:

If $A_1,...,A_n$ and $B_1,...,B_n$ are two sequences of subsets of $X=\{1,...,r\}$ such that $A_i\cap B_j = \emptyset$ if and only if $i=j$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{|A_i|+|B_i|}{|A_i|}^{-1}\leq 1.$$

> First of all, I am interested in the case where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are
>   complementary.

It means we obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{r}{|A_i|}^{-1}\leq 1.$$
from which we have the Sperner's theorem since $\binom{r}{\lfloor \frac{r}{2} \rfloor}^{-1}\leq \binom{r}{k}^{-1}$ for all $k$:
$$n\leq \binom{r}{\lfloor \frac{r}{2} \rfloor}.$$
For a given $n$, it is therefore easy to find the smallest value $r$ for which the previous inequality is verified.

> However, I am interested in a special case where there are additional
>   conditions on the $A_i$'s and $B_i$'s:
>
> $$|(A_i\cap B_j) \cup (A_{i+1}\cap B_{j+1})|\geq 2, \text{ for all } i\neq j.$$

How could I adapt the previous results with this additional condition?
That is, for a given $n$, how could I find the smallest integer $r$ such that all the conditions are verified?

I suppose that for a given $n$, the smallest integer $r$ for which there are such sets $A_i$ and $B_i$ will be bigger than without the additional conditions.

A way to prove the original problem is by counting the number of permutations separating a pair $(A,B)$ (see this [link](https://books.google.be/books?id=8-ipCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=Lubell%27s+method+of+counting+permutations&source=bl&ots=aoODsv0ae1&sig=Bv-ucoBm5RsCQB_MXFj0F8PzC90&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjajtab0LDKAhUMmBoKHRPNDP0Q6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=Lubell%27s%20method%20of%20counting%20permutations&f=false) for example).
However, I do not see how to adapt this approach.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Clearly the old proof still goes through if you have the additional assumption (since you don't need to actually *use* the assumption), and I think the standard example $A_i = \{1, \ldots, n\} \setminus \{i\}$, $B_i = \{i\}$ satisfies your extra assumption and shows that the upper bound is still best possible.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo I edited my question.

Comment: I doubt that this allows to get better bound.